# imagettftext php function in Hebrew language?

Tags: php

I need to write in Hebrew alphabet to imagettftext() GD2, how can I?

Here is the best solution at witch I come so far:

```
<?php
$language_into = 'he';
$im = ImageCreateFromPNG('test.png'); 
$black = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
ImageColorTransparent($im, $black);
ImageSaveAlpha($im, true);
$text = "בְּרֵאשִׁית";
//Reverse string for RTL languages 
switch($language_into)
{
    case 'he':
    case 'ar':
        preg_match_all ('/./us' , $text, $rtl);
        $text = join ('' , array_reverse($rtl[0])); 
    break;

    default:
    break;
}
//Link: http://titus.fkidg1.uni-frankfurt.de/unicode/tituut.asp
ImageTtfText($im, 18, 0, 12, 36, $black, "tituscbz.ttf", $text);
Header('Content-Type: image/png');
Header("Expires: Mon, 1, 1999 05:00:00 GMT");
Header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
Header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
Header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
Header("Pragma: no-cache");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: I missed the switch to reverse the text string for RTL languages here Hebrew and Arabic. But I edited the message after one day of diggings and no answer. Plus my first font DejaVuSerif.ttf has no code page for Hebrew alphabet also I edited my above post. Also works with Windows fonts such as Arial.ttf :-)